# OpenCV double free or corruption (out): Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c++, opencv, memory

Iḿ working on a algorithm to find and fill regions on a binarized image,the code work as expected for some images, but I don't know why, after the fourth image I always get this error:

> *** Error in `./heli': double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000001ccb610 ***
>   Aborted (core dumped)

This is my code:

```
void fillRegion(Mat src, Mat &dst, Point origin, Vec3b color)
{
    int size = 0;
    list<Point> cadena;
    cadena.push_back(origin);
    while(!cadena.empty())
    {
        Point current = cadena.front();
        cadena.pop_front();
        Point top,bot,right,left;
        top = bot = right = left = current;
        top.y -= 1;
        bot.y += 1;
        right.x += 1;
        left.x -= 1;
        Vec3b cero = Vec3b(0,0,0);

        if(top.y >= 0 && dst.at<Vec3b>(top) == cero && src.at<uchar>(top)!= 0)
        {
            dst.at<Vec3b>(top) = color;
            cadena.push_back(top);
        }
        if(bot.y <= src.rows && dst.at<Vec3b>(bot) == cero && src.at<uchar>(bot)!= 0)
        {
            dst.at<Vec3b>(bot) = color;
            cadena.push_back(bot);
        }
        if(right.x <= src.cols && dst.at<Vec3b>(right) == cero && src.at<uchar>(right)!= 0)
        {
            dst.at<Vec3b>(right) = color;
            cadena.push_back(right);
        }
        if(left.y >= 0 && dst.at<Vec3b>(left) == cero && src.at<uchar>(left)!= 0)
        {
            dst.at<Vec3b>(left) = color;
            cadena.push_back(left);
        }
    }
}

void segment(Mat src, Mat &dst)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < src.rows;  y++)
        {
            Point p = Point(x,y); 
            if(src.at<uchar>(p) != 0 && dst.at<Vec3b>(p) == Vec3b(0,0,0) )
            {
                fillRegion(src,dst,p,getRandomColor());
            }
        }    
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    namedWindow("Original", WINDOW_NORMAL); 
    namedWindow("Resultado", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    vector<string> archivos = vector<string>();
    getdir("../images",archivos);
    int tam = archivos.size();
    for(uint i = 0; i < tam; i++)
    {
        Mat img = imread(archivos[i],CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
        Mat newImg = Mat(img.rows,img.cols, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0,0,0));;
        threshold(img,img,125,255,THRESH_BINARY);
        imshow("Original", img);
        segment(img,newImg);
        imshow("Resultado", newImg);
        waitKey(0);
    }
}
```

I call the "Segment" method, which then calls the "fillRegion" method for each region found.
I know the error is at the "fillRegion" method, because if I comment it from "segment", the error is gone, but I just can't find/don't know what's the error on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have gdb (and you should), do the following:

```
gdb
run "your file name here"
core /[name of core file]
bt (stands for backtrace)
```

This will tell you where your code crashed.

Comment: Ok I dit that, and it tells me that the error is at this line on main:

`Mat newImg = Mat(img.rows,img.cols, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0,0,0));`

Specifically, at the call to Mat::release (which I never do)
But that doesn't tell me anything :/

Comment: Does Mat have a user-defined copy constructor that actually works?  I don't know, but if there is an error on that line, the likelihood is that it is using the compiler generated copy constructor, which may not be enough.

Comment: @edua_glz I would suggest doing just this: `Mat newImg(img.rows,img.cols, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0,0,0));` There is no need to invoke the copy constructor -- just create the variable. You make this same oversight in several other places in your code, where you're needlessly invoking the copy constructor when creating new objects.  Like here -- `Vec3b cero = Vec3b(0,0,0);`  This should just be `Vec3b cero(0,0,0);`

Comment: @edua_glz - Here is another `vector<string> archivos = vector<string>();`  I don't know why you suspected that C++ only can create objects using a copy constructor.  That line could be just this: `vector<string> archivos;`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ok I removed all the copy constructors, but the code still gives me the same error

Comment: @edua_glz What is the value of img.rows?  img.cols?  If the error is that function, then remove the code after it, run the program, and concentrate on that one function.  That is, *if* the error still occurs.  And probably `Mat::release` was called due to the copy constructor being invoked, and the behavior described here:  http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html#mat  was kicked in (the reference counting).

Comment: The size of the previous images is (20x20, 1132x1132,314x314, 512x512)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has to do with the copy constructor other than the fact that it fails to allocate enough memory. As you mentioned, commenting out the `fillRegion` call in `segment` avoids the seg fault. This likely means that there is a memory leak in `fillRegion` that is filling up the allotted memory size within 4 iterations of your program.

While this won't solve your memory leak, I suggest passing `Mat src` instead as `const Mat& src`. Passing by reference will avoid an unnecessary copy in this case since you aren't internally modifying anything in `src`.

My guess that the memory leak has to do with these two checks: 
    `bot.y <= src.rows`
    `right.x <= src.cols`

I believe that they should instead be strictly less than (`<`) to avoid calling `at` on an invalid point. When calling `at` on a point that is outside the current `Mat`'s dimensions, does it resize? If that is the case, then you are constantly resizing these images whenever you hit these boundaries. There's your memory leak

One more thing: can `getRandomColor()` potentially return `(0, 0, 0)`? If so, this program could run into an infinite loop

Comment: I made both changes as you suggested, but the error is still there

Comment: According to the doc's here:  http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html#mat  The copy constructor uses a reference counting mechanism, and doesn't actually copy the data.  However, I agree the OP should pass by const reference, just to avoid all of that.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this like I did, adding exit(0) as the last line in my code fixed the segfault for me on ubuntu 16.04.