# How do I send data back along the second pipe in the correct format?

Tags: c++, process, pipe, parent-child

I have been struggling for two days to attempt to fix this final bug in my code, but can't seem to find the error. The code is supposes to(in order):

1. Receive a string from the user (in this case me)
2. Create a child process
3. Send the string to the child process
4. Rework the string so that every word starts with a capital letter
5. Send the string back to the parent with the changes
6. Display the string

The code runs fine until the parent read. An example output is:

Input: "helLO tHerE"

Parent writes "helLO tHerE"

Child reads "helLO tHerE"

Child writes "Hello There"

Parent reads @#$%^$#%^&* - or some other such non-standard characters, then displays error -

double free or corruption (out): 0x00007ffeeebb2690 ***

Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int fd[2];
    int pfc[2];
    int status = 0;
    string val = "";

    if(pipe(fd) == -1 || pipe(pfc) == -1) fprintf(stderr,"Pipe failed");

    pid_t pid = fork();

    // fork() returns 0 for child process, child-pid for parent process.
    if (pid == 0){   // child: reading only, so close the write-descriptor
        string writeval = "";
        close(fd[1]);

        // now read the data (will block)
        read(fd[0], &val, sizeof(val));
        cout << "Child reads " << val.c_str() << endl;
        string temp = " " + val;
        transform(temp.begin(), temp.end(), temp.begin(), ::tolower);
        for(size_t i = 1; i < temp.length(); i++){
            if(!isspace(temp[i]) && isspace(temp[i-1])){
                temp[i] = toupper(temp[i]);
            }
        }
        writeval = temp.substr(1, temp.length() - 1);

        // close the read-descriptor
        close(fd[0]);
        close(pfc[0]);
        cout << "Child writes " << writeval.c_str() << endl;

        write(pfc[1], &writeval, sizeof(writeval));

        close(pfc[1]);
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        string readval = "";
        string temp ="";
        // parent: writing only, so close read-descriptor.
        close(fd[0]);

       // send the value on the write-descriptor.
        while(getline(cin, temp)){
            val += temp;
        }
        write(fd[1], &val, sizeof(val));

        cout << "Parent writes " << val << endl;
        // close the write descriptor
        close(fd[1]);
        //wait(&status);
        close(pfc[1]);
        read(pfc[0], &readval, sizeof(readval));
        cout << "Parent reads " << readval << endl;
        close(pfc[0]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is simple. In the child process I was passing the memory location of writeval in the write back to the parent method, but in the parent process I was trying to read from the memory location of readval. This is fixed by changing them to be the same variable, outside of the if/else calls, like was done with the variable val.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365244/what-causes-double-free-or-corruption-out-error) for more details on why this is a problem.